# Write a reducer function that immutably adds a new item into a nested store property

Tags: reactjs, redux

I cannot write a correct return statement in the reducer function that keeps all the existing properties in the `completeExercises` and just adds a new property to the end of the list:

My state now looks like:

```
user: {
  completeExercises: {
    1p3223cyn5x: {
     complete: true
    }
  },
  entries: ""
}
```

And after I call the action and pass another exercises' id through payload I want it to keep all the existing `completeExercises` and add the one I pass to the list:

```
user: {
  completeExercises: {
    1p3223cyn5x: {
      complete: true
    },
    2ky16b0v2kg: {
      complete: true
    }
  },
  entries: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to preserve the already existing properties and add one to the end of the list, your reducer `return` statement should look like:

```
return {
        ...state,
        completeExercises: {
          ...state.completeExercises,
          [payload.id]: {
            complete: true
          }
        },
        entries: {
          ...state.entries
        },
      };
```

Comment: There is no need to copy `entries` into a new object if they don't change. They are actually already covered in `...state`.